# Ajax reload div content on click button

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

The idea is: i have a main DIV with content mini divs of cars info divided two per row, that i'm getting with a query from DB, i want when pressing that button to make reload of that main content with new content from the DB, is that possible to do ? please advise.

code looks like this:

```
<div class="SearchBlocks">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="car_section">INFO</div>
        <div class="car_section">INFO</div>
        <div class="car_section">INFO</div>
        <div class="car_section">INFO</div>
        ......

    </div>
    <h2 class="load_more"><a id="more_link" href="#">Load more <i class="icon-custom_arrow"></i></a></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: That is possible. What have you tried so far? Also, what back-end technology and database are you using.

Comment: @Kenneth it's WP custom with PHP MySQL, i don't have quite experience with this, so didn't try much really...

Comment: Well, you need to show some effort at least. SO is not a programmer-for-free website. There are plenty of examples out there on the web. I suggest you try something and when you get really stuck, you can come back and ask a specific question

Comment: @Kenneth As you can see it's not the actual code, so i'm not trying to solve my personal problem, i'm trying to get the best solution for this Ajax reloading for others too

Answer (score 3):

```
    function reload(url){
       $.get(url, function(data){      // $.get will get the content of the page defined in url and will return it in **data** variable 
            $('#row').append(data);
       }
    }

$('#more_link').click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = 'http://example.com/somepage.html';
        reload(url);  // this calls the reload function
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; can you please write some description to it?

Comment: and don't forget that ajax only works if the url is in the same domain  (and subdomain). it will not work for urls from other sites

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the exact code you're using to generate your AJAX request, however the general pattern will be something like this, where the update logic is extracted in to it's own function which is called both on load of the page, and click of the `#reload_cars` button.

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'yoururl.foo',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#row .car_section').remove();
            $('#row').append(data);
        }
    });
}
$('#reload_cars').on('click', getData);
getData();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i forgot to mention that the URL is not static, that page is loaded from a search so will be like: `URL/New-york` and `URL/Las-Vegas` ... etc, how can i add the `url` in your code for this situation of mine?

Comment: @Jimmy, I think you should really update your OP with much more detail. You can append the URL with the value required: `url: 'URL/' + location`, assuming `location` is the variable holding the value

Comment: I tried with a specific URL and tested that page, but the code is not quite working, nothing happens, just goes to first of the page and changes URL to `URL/#'

Comment: Again, please update your question with details of your code. I can't debug something I can't see ;)

Comment: Thanks Rory! yes i update it the HTML with more details, the data from the inside the main div comes from a query without limitation so it's like 30 40 results, i want limited it to 10 and want to load the next 10 and remove the first ten, something like that

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
    function refreshDiv(){
       var container = document.getElementById("divId");
       var content = container.innerHTML;
       container.innerHTML= content;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! `document.getElementById("divId");` but where is the `divId` in your code?

Comment: "divId" is the id of div that you want reload