# Ajax Reload Button

Tags: python, html, ajax

I am trying to put a simple python script (here I've used a random two-word generator which works fine) in a div on a webpage with Ajax and have a button beneath that reloads it. The page successfully loads the script... ***however***, I haven't quite got my head around the missing part to call the script again to reload the random two words made by the python script (I understand why the code below is wrong but I can't work out how to make it right!). Pointer much appreciated!

(N.B. Yes I am using Python 2.4 because my web host hasn't upgraded yet - they will soon! And yes I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889100/ajax-reload-div-content-on-click-button) question but it didn't work for me...)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Find a sentence</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "cgi-bin/test.py",
                type: "GET",
                data: {foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo'},
                success: function(response){
                        $("#div").html(response);
                    }
           });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div"></div>

<form name="input" action="cgi-bin/test.py" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="Regenerate!">
</form>

</body>
```

PYTHON:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

import linecache
from random import randrange

print "Content-Type: text/html"
print

# file length counter

def file_len(fname):
    f = open(fname)
    try:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    finally:
        f.close()
    return i + 1

# range sizes

one_size = file_len('text/one.csv')
two_size = file_len('text/two.csv')

# random lines

one_line = randrange(one_size) + 1
two_line = randrange(two_size) + 1

# outputs

one_out = linecache.getline('text/one.csv', one_line)
two_out = linecache.getline('text/two.csv', two_line)

# output

sentence = one_out.strip('\n') + " " + two_out.strip('\n') + " "
print sentence
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would assume that one has to click on the "Regenerate" button for the form to reload. My idea would be to have the ajax logic in a separate function. I don't think you need the form there since your reload call is now ajax call.

```
<head>
<script>
    function reload() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "cgi-bin/test.py",
            type: "GET",
            data: {foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo'},
            dataType : "html",
            success: function(response){
                    $("#div").html(response);
                }
       });
    }

    $(window).load(function() {
        reload();
        $("#reload_button").click(function() {
            reload();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="div"></div>
    <input type="button" id="reload_button" value="Regenerate!">
</body>
```

Comment: Wonderful! This worked perfectly. Just need to learn what you did now :)

Comment: Its pretty straightforward. I created  a function called reload which when called would execute the ajax call to get the relevant data from thw backend. Then I made sure that the reload function is called when the page finishes loading. I also ensures that once the page finishes loading, a click event is associated with the regenerate button. When the button us clicked, the reload function is called again.